# Finding numbers of days between 2 dates in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code (Laravel Blade):

```
<div>{{ $user->paid_for_date  }} (xxxx days)</div>
```

paid_for_date - is date (ex 2020.05.15).
How can I display the number of days for a given day in the Laravel Blade view (paid_for_date - today's date)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use Carbon and calculate it in your controller like this

import the carbon namespace in your controller

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

and then calculate the date difference like this

```
$date = Carbon::parse($user->paid_for_date);
$now = Carbon::now();

$diff = $date->diffInDays($now);
```

and return the $diff to the view